# Impossible to destroy data, action destroy redirect to show page, whatever the model

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, destroy

I tried to destroy a data from the index page of User model and I realised that I could not do it and this is the same for all my models. I went to my microposts model and it is still impossible to destroy any data.
Each time I am redirected to the show page.

On the internet it is said that the problem can come from the `application.js` file but in that file I required jquery_ujs.

```js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

I tried to remove dataTables but nothing change.

Then I found that the problem could be with the way that the destroy action is written.

But my destroy action is well defined, all the more so as it has been written when using the `scaffold generator` with the command `rails generate scaffold User name:string`

This is the line for destroying an entity.

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `application.js` is fine.

Can you provide more information?

What is the `action` in the form generated by the `link_to` helper method when you analyze the source code?

Do you have a `before_filter` for authentication in place?

`byebug` would really help in your case

Comment: When you say before_filter for authentication it would be a restriction on who can destroy or no ? If it is this actually my application allow everyone of doing everything for the moment. I have by default in my GemFile the byebug gem..How can I use it ? It is written on the internet to insert "byebug"  before the line we want to test in a method. Is that all ?

Comment: Insert `byebug` in your controller `destroy` action and when it hits that action, you can use the console to verify information like `params`